# Implementing PATCH in webapi

Tags: asp.net, json, http, asp.net-web-api

I have an object that I want to update partially using webapi/json here is an example of my model

```
   public class Location
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public string PostalCode { get; set; }
    }
```

The JSON from the client will be

```
 {
    "Id": 1, 
    "Address":"new address" 
  }
```

The webapi function looks like this

```
    public bool Patch(Location location)
    {
        //do something
    }
```

Problem is the only field updated was the address so without checking each field for string.isnullorempty I can't tell what has changed and more over null/empty could just mean delete the value is there a more seamless way to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10332809/asp-web-api-patch-implementation

Comment: I saw this but it seemed a little strange that webapi didn't have  something like this out of the box because it seems like this would be a common desire.

Answer (score 2):

JSON Patch is not natively supported by ASP.NET Web API. There are currently two implementations for the JSON-patch spec that are available for .NET (at least that I'm aware of):

**myquay/JsonPatch**
Github: https://github.com/myquay/JsonPatch
NuGet: https://www.nuget.org/packages/JsonPatch/1.0.0

**KevinDockx/JsonPatch**
GitHub: https://github.com/KevinDockx/JsonPatch
NuGet: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Marvin.JsonPatch/0.3.0

Both of these are currently in "alpha" status, and neither of them implement the spec fully yet.

Comment: Sounds like native support for JsonPatch is coming to ASP.NET 5: https://blogs.realdolmen.com/experts/2015/05/05/partial-updates-for-your-restful-api-with-jsonpatch-in-the-new-asp-net-5/

Answer (score 1):

Not really.  That's why there is [Json-patch](http://jsonpatch.com/) however, to my knowledge no-one has written a .net library for it.